# How to exit from nested python scripts?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, exit

I have two python scripts call `a.py` and `b.py`.

From inside `a.py`, I am giving command

```
os.system('python b.py')
```

If some exception is found in `b.py`, I want the complete execution of both `a.py` and `b.py` to be halted. Is there a way to do that?

I am not importing `b.py` in `a.py`. I am simply calling it using `os.system()`.

How can the same be achieved even if I import the other script?

Answer (score 1):

[os.system()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) returns the (encoded) process exit value. 0 means success.

I would rather reccomend the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) Module since it is more powerful. Take a look at `subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)`.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you import a module `b` that might raise an exception which you won't handle, either let the exception halt the execution by not handling it, or, handle it and `exit` yourself.

If you opt for calling `os.system` check the error code returned; if Python doesn't exit gracefully (i.e an exception was raised) it is going to be a non `0` value. You can test on and act accordingly:

```
if os.system('python b.py'):
    # exit from script a.by
```